# How do I make a ticket?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked a question that could not be answered, and was requested to make a ticket about it.

How do I make a ticket?

I am signed up at code.ros.org and looking at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/wiki/TracTickets tells me a lot about tickets, but I still can't figure out how to actually make a ticket.  At the very bottom of that page it did have info about how to make a ticket by creating a custom url and pushing that to the server... not exactly what I am looking for.  Surely there is a nice "New Ticket" button somewhere that I have overlooked...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9632/how-do-i-make-a-ticket?/) by [veltrop](https://answers.ros.org/users/42/veltrop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 295 on 2011-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are logged in while viewing e.g. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/wiki/TracTickets , you should find a "New Ticket" link in the top right, under the search box and above the table of contents for that page. Note that you will not see this link if you are not logged into code.ros.org . If you are, you will see something to the effect of "logged in as *username*" in the links underneath the search box.

It will take you to this URL: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket . Once you have filled in your ticket info on that page, click "Preview" to make sure your ticket formatted as you expected. Then click "Create Ticket" to submit the ticket.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [veltrop](https://answers.ros.org/users/42/veltrop/) on 2011-04-03**:
I finally see it!  I swear it wasn't there before ;) I even used the View Tickets button and still missed it. I even highlighted all words on the page that said ticket and still missed it!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Drink some coffee and take another look at the page :P

---

Originally posted by [veltrop](https://answers.ros.org/users/42/veltrop/) with karma: 295 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1